# Updating useState from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-hooks

what is a good practice to update the variable in component using variable passed by props from other components? Here I'm trying to display image based on 'id' passed from different component where I catch the id based onClick event. Sadly my `useState` component do not update in 100%. Somehow it is possible to correctly read the proper index, but it doesn't display the image properly.

```
const SwiperModal = ({ handleClose, show, membersList, curr_idx }) => {
  const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
  const idx = parseInt(curr_idx);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(idx);

  return (
    <div className={showHideClassName}>
      <section className="modal-main">
        <button className="btn__close" onClick={handleClose}>
          close
        </button>
        <Gallery
          index={index}
          //index variable above is responsible for "which image is displayed from the list"
          onRequestChange={i => {
            setIndex(i);
          }}
        >
          {membersList.map((value, index) => (
            <GalleryImage objectFit="contain" src={value.image} key={index} />
          ))}
        </Gallery>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Is it a good approach to update variables like that using props passed from other components ? or there is other idea to do this?

Comment: I don't see where you're using the index to specify an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a listener for `curr_idx` change or your state won't update on props change (caused by `onClick`), you can achieve it with [`useEffect` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect):

```
const SwiperModal = ({ handleClose, show, membersList, curr_idx }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(parseInt(curr_idx));

  useEffect(() => {
    setIndex(parseInt(curr_idx));
  }, [curr_idx]);

  return (...);
};
```